# Join SQL table using the same row but different view/column output

Tags: sql, sql-server

***Edit**: The initial issue is addressed with the answer below. I have one further question - Now that I see the "Linked" and "Not Linked" counts, I am trying to get percentage of "Linked" by `COUNT("Article Link")/COUNT(*) as "Percentage"`, but it shows just '0' or '1' and not actual percentage.*

--------------Original issue------------

I have the below table.

```
CaseNumber  Owner   Article Link
ABC1234     John    Linked
ABC2345     Alex    Linked
ABC3456     John    Linked
ABC4567     Maria   Linked
ABC5678     Maria   
ABC6789     John    
ABC7900     Alex    
ABC9011     Issac   Linked
ABC10122    Issac   Linked
ABC11233    Issac   Linked
ABC12344    Issac   Linked
ABC13455    Issac   Linked
ABC14566    Maria   Linked
ABC15677    Maria   Linked
ABC16788    Maria   Linked
ABC17899    John    Linked
ABC19010    John
```

And I am trying to get an output like the below, i.e. group by "Owner" with the count of "Linked" and "Not Linked".

```
**Owner Linked  Not Linked**
Alex    1       1
Issac   5       
John    3       2
Maria   4       1
```

I have tried the below and this gives result individually, but a self join or and inner/left join doesn't help either.

```
SELECT  Owner, count(Owner) AS "Linked"
FROM Linking_Table 
Where "Article Link"  = 'Linked'
GROUP BY Owner

SELECT  Owner, count(Owner) AS "Not Linked"
FROM Linking_Table 
Where "Article Link" is NULL
GROUP BY Owner
```

And tried this as well. No luck.

```
SELECT  Owner, count(Owner) AS "Linked", count(Owner) AS "Not Linked"
FROM Linking_Table 
WHERE "Article Link"  = 'Linked' OR "Article Link" is NULL
GROUP BY Owner
```

Can anyone suggest, what am I missing or point me t any documentation?

Comment: Hint: `count()` counts non-null values only.

Comment: Are you storing empty strings or NULL (in the Article Link column)?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Oracle?)

Comment: Its SQL server. And the columns are NULL

Comment: Are you really sure the accepted answer gives you the expected result?

Comment: Yes it does and I have the output, as desired. Its "Query to calculate Link Percentage" piece really.

Comment: The accepted answer only works when using zero-length strings instead of `NULL`. It's important to differentiate between `NULL` and `''` because `CASE WHEN NULL <> 'Linked' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` returns `0`, not `1`. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5098b2ac4ab39b274ff117ba04e522ee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation as below:

Scheman and insert statements:

```
CREATE TABLE Linking_Table (CaseNumber VARCHAR(20),  Owner VARCHAR(20),   Article_Link VARCHAR(20))


INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC1234','John','Linked');
INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC2345','Alex','Linked');
INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC3456','John','Linked');
INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC4567','Maria','Linked');
INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC5678','Maria','');   
INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC6789','John','');    
INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC7900','Alex','');    
INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC9011','Issac','Linked');
INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC10122','Issac','Linked');
INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC11233','Issac','Linked');
INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC12344','Issac','Linked');
INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC13455','Issac','Linked');
INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC14566','Maria','Linked');
INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC15677','Maria','Linked');
INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC16788','Maria','Linked');
INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC17899','John','Linked');
INSERT INTO Linking_Table VALUES('ABC19010','John','');
```

Query:

```
SELECT Owner,sum(case when Article_Link='Linked' then 1 end) Linked,
sum(case when Article_Link<>'Linked' then 1 end) Not_Linked  
FROM Linking_Table
group by Owner
order by Owner
```

Output:

| Owner | Linked | Not_Linked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 1 | 1 |
| Issac | 5 | *null* |
| John | 3 | 2 |
| Maria | 4 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1156e900feb54f66a1d91f87e4bc6433)*

Query to calculate Link Percentage:

```
 SELECT Owner,sum(case when Article_Link='Linked' then 1 end) Linked,
 sum(case when Article_Link<>'Linked' then 1 end) Not_Linked,
 100*sum(case when Article_Link='Linked' then 1 end)/count(*) inked_percentage
 FROM Linking_Table
 group by Owner
 order by Owner
```

Output:

| Owner | Linked | Not_Linked | linked_percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 1 | 1 | 50 |
| Issac | 5 | *null* | 100 |
| John | 3 | 2 | 60 |
| Maria | 4 | 1 | 80 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a99f83096fb9848ddcc335de345bd042)*

Comment: That worked for me. If I can ask one further question - Now that I see the "Linked" and "Not Linked" counts, I am trying to get percentage of "Linked" by COUNT("Article Link")/COUNT(*) as "Percentage" , but it shows just '0' or '1'.

Comment: @AnitKumar I have revised my answer with solution to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(*)` counts all the rows in a group.

`COUNT(column_name)` counts all the rows where `column_name` is `NOT NULL`

```
SELECT
  Owner,
  COUNT("Article Link") AS "Linked",
  COUNT(*) - COUNT("Article Link") AS "Not Linked"
FROM
  Linking_Table 
WHERE
     "Article Link"  = 'Linked'
  OR "Article Link" IS NULL
GROUP BY
  Owner
```

Comment: That worked for me. If I can ask one further question - Now that I see the "Linked" and "Not Linked" counts,  I am trying to get percentage of "Linked" by COUNT("Article Link")/COUNT(*) as "Percentage" , but it shows just '0' or '1'. @MatBailie . Any suggestions ?

Comment: @AnitKumar Your operands are integers and so the result is an integer. Either explicitly cast one to a float or decimal, or multiply by 1.0 before the division (to implicitly coerce the data type).